# psycopg3 pool "connection is closed"

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, psycopg3

I have set up a decorator to provide a db connection using psycopg3. Sometimes, the connection is closed and it is throwing the following error when I try to use it:

> the connection is closed

Here is my implementation:

```py
master_connection_pool = psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool(
    conninfo=masterDbConnectionString,
    min_size=5,
    open=True
)

def provide_db(func):
    """
    Function decorator that provides a session if it isn't provided.
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        arg_session = 'db'

        func_params = func.__code__.co_varnames
        session_in_args = arg_session in func_params and \
                          func_params.index(arg_session) < len(args)
        session_in_kwargs = arg_session in kwargs

        if session_in_kwargs and kwargs[arg_session] is not None:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        if session_in_args and args[func_params.index(arg_session)] is not None:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            with master_connection_pool.connection() as conn:
                conn.row_factory = dict_row
                kwargs[arg_session] = conn
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Then in my app I can do this:

```py
@provide_db
def do_Stuff(user_id, db):
    db.query(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={user_id}")
    ...
```

What is the proper way to reconnect or prevent this from happening, this is a webapp so its a long running process.

Comment: It is possible there is a race condition between grabbing a connection from the pool, and that connection closing for some reason. Maybe you could try wrapping the `with` block in a try/catch block.

Comment: The thing is it consistently occurs when the app process has been running for 24+ hours. Not random like a race condition.

Comment: Also it is not clear what you are doing with the `session_in_kwargs` stuff. I'd assume the `db` connection should always come from the pool though, because doing two layers of caching seems redundant. I might be misunderstanding your code though.

Comment: it's just checking if there is a params passed in, either as a positional argument or a kwarg that is called `db` and is not none. If there is no such param in the call, it adds one.

Comment: Maybe try `yield from` inside the decorator function, instead of returning.

Comment: "The thing is it consistently occurs when the app process has been running for 24+ hours" -> have you checked for external factors, such as firewalls / routers dropping connections after a fixed time, or settings in `postgresql.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

From the [document](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html#psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool.connection) I see the connection is not closed, instead, it's put back in the pool so it's reused.

> Upon context exit, return the connection to the pool. Apply the normal connection context behaviour (commit/rollback the transaction in case of success/error). If the connection is no more in working state, replace it with a new one.

I can think of 3 approaches:

1. To use check function([doc link](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html#psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool.check)), But this looks like an overhead.
2. To use values that are aligned with db conf. Arguments like `max_idle` and `max_lifetime` can be used to control the pool behavior. you can read more about them [here](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html#the-connectionpool-class).
3. Use [NullConnectionPool](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html#psycopg_pool.NullConnectionPool) instead.

I hope you will be able to fix it If you play around with these.

Comment: I would add that the psycopg author explicitly said that "[max_lifetime is the wrong knob](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/issues/247#issuecomment-1378893531)" to handle dead connections. One might also consider external probes such as k8s healthchecks for long running services.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite your class and function to be more resilient to connection errors, you can do the following:

```py
import psycopg2
import psycopg_pool
from functools import wraps

class ReconnectingConnectionPool(psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool):
    def connection(self):
        try:
            return super().connection()
        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            self.close()
            return super().connection()

def provide_db(func):
    """
    Function decorator that provides a session if it isn't provided.
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        arg_session = 'db'

        func_params = func.__code__.co_varnames
        session_in_args = arg_session in func_params and \
                          func_params.index(arg_session) < len(args)
        session_in_kwargs = arg_session in kwargs

        if session_in_kwargs and kwargs[arg_session] is not None:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        if session_in_args and args[func_params.index(arg_session)] is not None:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            with ReconnectingConnectionPool(conninfo=masterDbConnectionString) as conn:
                conn.row_factory = dict_row
                kwargs[arg_session] = conn
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

The main change is to use a `ReconnectingConnectionPool` instead of a regular `ConnectionPool`. This will ensure that the connection pool will automatically reconnect to the database if a connection is closed.

Another change is to wrap the `conn.connection()` call in a `try/except` block. This will catch any connection errors and reconnect to the database if necessary.

Finally, I have added a check to the `wrapper` function to ensure that the connection pool is closed before the function returns. This is not strictly necessary, but it is good practice to close connection pools when you are finished using them.

Example usage:

```
@provide_db
def get_user(user_id, db):
    db.query(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={user_id}")
    ...

user = get_user(123, db)
```

Sources: [1](https://qiita.com/ijufumi/items/c30bb9fee9d1ab8cfd18), [2](https://www.wake-up-neo.net/es/python/como-cerrar-correctamente-las-conexiones-mysql-en-sqlalchemy/836460100/)

Comment: The question was specifically about psycopg (3), while your answer is about psycopg2, which has a very different API.